# convert chars form char array to integer in C

Tags: c

from a char array like {T,E,S,T,1,2,3,E,N,D}, I need to get an integer from certain positions. Following with the example, I would like to get an integer from positions 4, 5, 6. So, myInt = 123.
    I tried following method but haven't got desired integer.

```
char  receivedata[bytes];

concatVars = concatenate(atoi(receivedata[6] - '0', receivedata[7] - '0');
concatVars = concatenate(concatVars, receivedata[8] - '0');

unsigned concatenate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return x * pow + y;
}
```

Comment: Make a function, test if its an int, subtract '0', take the result times 10^xth where x=a function of the number of positions requested together, return the summation... Give it a stab

Comment: Assuming this *is*, in fact, correct C code: How are the variables or macros `T`, `E`, `S` (etcetera) defined? Are these integers as well?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting answers below without comment ... STOP IT.

Comment: agree... every answer is always useful or, at least, please comment it if downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int arrToInt(char* arr, int len) {
  int toRet = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (isdigit(arr[i])) {
      toRet *= 10;
      toRet += arr[i] - '0';
    }
  }
  return toRet;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char test[] = {'T', 'E', 'S', 'T', '1', '2', '3', 'E', 'N', 'D'};

  int asInt = arrToInt(test, 10);
  printf("Got: %d\n", asInt);
}
```

Output (compiling with -std=c99 to make the `int i = 0` inline declaration work):

> Got: 123

Comment: Yes, if the downvoter would like to explain, I'd be happy to fix whatever problem you see.

Comment: I suspect that it is a certain well-known person who punishes people for answering questions he doesn't approve of.

Comment: @JimBalter Who's the well known person, out of curiosity?

Comment: Since it's only a suspicion, I'm not going to name anyone.

Comment: While I'm not the downvoter, I still don't see the point in re-implementing a standard library function from scratch. The above implementation, for example, suffers from the lack of overflow protection.

Comment: @AndreyT Which library function? `atoi`? I don't think that meets the OP's needs. There's no guarantee that the substring of numeric `char`s is continuous, for example.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: No. Not `atoi`. `atoi` would suffer from the same overflow problem. Functions from `strto...` group are the ones available for this conversion. As for the sequence not being continuous - I don't see any hint of anything like that in the original question. I think the OP made it clear that the objective is to convert consecutive character positions.

Comment: Of course it could easily turn out that this is a training assignment of sorts, the whole point of which is to have the student to manually implement this function... I don't know.

Comment: @AndreyT My understanding was that it needed to handle stuff like `"T1ES2T34"`, the most general case.

Comment: @Patrick Collins: From the original wording of the question I'd rater conclude that `"T1ES2T34"` should produce three separate numbers: `1`, `2`, and `34`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be:

```
int myInt = (((int)myArray[4] - 48) * 100) + (((int)myArray[5] - 48) * 10) + (((int)myArray[6] - 48) * 1);
```

Note that 48 is the ASCII position of the number 0, thus by converting a character to int and then subtracting 48 you get the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Standard library's string-to-integer conversion functions (e.g. `strtol`) stop automatically once they reach a non-numeric character in the input character sequence. So all you have to do is tell such function where to start. In your case this will perform the conversion

```
  const char *s = "TEST123END";

  long myLong = strtol(s + 4, NULL, 10);

  int myInt = myLong;
```

You just have to handle possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
int myInt = atoi(&myArray[4]);
```

Adding to ced-b's response, I prefer this syntax:

```
myArray[5] - '0'
```

That is, make it clear you are subtracting off the '0'.

Note: I used specific offset into the string because the OP asked for: "I need to get an integer from certain positions", which I interpreted as specific offset into the string.  Based on the accepted answer I seem to have interpreted that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *str = "TEST123END";
    char s4_6[4] = {0};
    int n;
    memcpy(s4_6, str+4, 3);
    //if(1==sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%d", &n))
    //if(1==sscanf(str+4, "%d", &n))
    if(1==sscanf(s4_6, "%d", &n))
        printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about getting an integer from "certain positions". If you're going to answer this (and I don't think it should be answered), I think the positions should be specified. Update: the OP's question has been updated now refers to specific positions.